# JavaScript identifiers not to use

Tags: javascript

I just found out the hard way that naming your variable `arguments` is a bad idea.

```
var arguments = 5;

(function () { 
    console.log(arguments); 
})();
```

> `Output: []`

It turns out that `arguments` is ["a local variable available within all functions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) so in each new execution context, `arguments` is shadowed.

My question is: Are there any other such treacherous names which, like `arguments`, are not true [reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), but will cause still problems?

Comment: There are no other automatic symbols inside functions (apart from `this`), if that's what you mean. Though there are a couple of default global variables, so defining a variable with the same name inside the function will shadow the global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no other automatic symbols inside functions (apart from `this`, but you cannot create a variable with that name anyway), if that's what you mean. But there are a couple of default global variables, so defining a variable with the same name inside the function will shadow the global variable.

Comment: It can shadow, but it also might not shadow - that is completely up to the browser, so the last sentence is wrong. That's (also) why those global objects are also problematic and are not just regular, predefined variables.

Comment: @eis: According to the spec, if there is a local variable with a certain name and this name is accessed inside the function, the value of that variable is returned (http://es5.github.com/#x10.2.2.1). Only if there is no such symbol in the current lexical environment, the "next higher" one is tested. That's what I meant. Or what are you referring to? Do you mean that not every variable declaration in a function creates a symbol? Either way, could you give a concrete example?

Comment: @FelixKing Ok, I think I know now where's the difference. Example I had in mind: `var window = 5; (function () { window = 6; alert(window); })();` - alert will still reference to the window object, and not the value we've assigned to it. But with `var` within the function we explicitly assign it to function scope only, in which case it would work. But it wouldn't work with the OP's example - simply because variable is declared in the global namespace instead of function namespace, and there it will clash with the global object.

Comment: Ok got it. Yeah, if you try to declare a variable in global scope that already exists there, the declaration is ignored. In addition some properties of `window` are read only.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Like `window` or `document`, for example. See a longer list [here](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm) ("other javascript keywords").

Wouldn't recommend using any of them, even though some would work as intended.

Edit: Like mentioned in [javascript.about.com](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm), "While they are not reserved words, the use of those words as variables and functions should be avoided.". They are listing mostly the same things classified as [predefined classes and objects](http://javascript.about.com/library/blclassobj.htm) and [global properties](http://javascript.about.com/library/blglobal.htm).

Example of a problem:

```
var window = 5;

(function () { 
    alert(window); 
})();
```

the code above has unpredictable results due to fact that `window` is the word to refer to the window object. Firefox prevents modifications to it, so alert will still refer to window object, whereas in IE8, you'll get alert with value `5`.

Comment: That page seems to built on a misunderstanding of what keywords are and the categories seem to make little sense. `window` and `document` are global variables and behave as such, that's it...

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz: If you have a better list, you're welcome to post it as an answer. Don't downvote perfectly good answers only because you disagree with the categorisation of some words.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz Maybe, but I think that's beside the point anyway - OP was asking for "other such treacherous names which, like arguments, are not true reserved words, but will cause still problems", and that's certainly what they are. I wasn't claiming that they are keywords.

Comment: I don't believe `window` and `document` will cause similar problems. They are just global variables and unlike `arguments` they will be shadowed exactly as expected. If you define your own global variables, they will behave exactly the same as `window` and `document`. They are not by any means keywords either, so I believe the downvote is correct.

Comment: @FelixKling gave a good and correct answer as a comment to the original question.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz Ok, then you're of the different opinion - I hold a firm belief that overwriting them does cause issues. But I added an additional reference to make that more clear.

Comment: Ok, I will stay out of a lengthy dispute here but you *can* definitely define a local variable with the name `document` without breaking anything anywhere else in the code.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz the comment in the original question was about what happens in the context of a javascript function. I don't see such limitation in the question.

Comment: @eis: He's saying the same on my answer. Apparently, only his interpretation of the question is the right one.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz I'd like to give an example. Suppose a code `var window = 1; alert(window); function f() { alert(window); } f();`. alert will refer to `window` object in firefox, but variable with value `1` in IE8. Don't you see that as a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all names used in the global namespace, by executing this in the console:

```
var t = [];
for(v in this){t.push(v)}
console.log(t.sort());
```

Result:

```
["$","ArrayBuffer","Attr","Audio","AudioProcessingEvent","BeforeLoadEvent","Blob","CDATASection","CSSCharsetRule","CSSFontFaceRule","CSSImportRule","CSSMediaRule","CSSPageRule","CSSPrimitiveValue","CSSRule","CSSRuleList","CSSStyleDeclaration","CSSStyleRule","CSSStyleSheet","CSSValue","CSSValueList","CTIsPlayback","CanvasGradient","CanvasPattern","CanvasRenderingContext2D","CharacterData","ClientRect","ClientRectList","Clipboard","CloseEvent","Comment","CompositionEvent","Counter","CustomEvent","DOMException","DOMImplementation","DOMParser","DOMSettableTokenList","DOMStringList","DOMStringMap","DOMTokenList","DataView","DeviceOrientationEvent","Document","DocumentFragment","DocumentType","Element","Entity","EntityReference","ErrorEvent","Event","EventEmitter","EventException","EventSource","File","FileError","FileList","FileReader","Float32Array","Float64Array","FormData","Generator","HTMLAllCollection","HTMLAnchorElement","HTMLAppletElement","HTMLAreaElement","HTMLAudioElement","HTMLBRElement","HTMLBaseElement","HTMLBaseFontElement","HTMLBodyElement","HTMLButtonElement","HTMLCanvasElement","HTMLCollection","HTMLDListElement","HTMLDataListElement","HTMLDirectoryElement","HTMLDivElement","HTMLDocument","HTMLElement","HTMLEmbedElement","HTMLFieldSetElement","HTMLFontElement","HTMLFormElement","HTMLFrameElement","HTMLFrameSetElement","HTMLHRElement","HTMLHeadElement","HTMLHeadingElement","HTMLHtmlElement","HTMLIFrameElement","HTMLImageElement","HTMLInputElement","HTMLKeygenElement","HTMLLIElement","HTMLLabelElement","HTMLLegendElement","HTMLLinkElement","HTMLMapElement","HTMLMarqueeElement","HTMLMediaElement","HTMLMenuElement","HTMLMetaElement","HTMLMeterElement","HTMLModElement","HTMLOListElement","HTMLObjectElement","HTMLOptGroupElement","HTMLOptionElement","HTMLOutputElement","HTMLParagraphElement","HTMLParamElement","HTMLPreElement","HTMLProgressElement","HTMLQuoteElement","HTMLScriptElement","HTMLSelectElement","HTMLSourceElement","HTMLSpanElement","HTMLStyleElement","HTMLTableCaptionElement","HTMLTableCellElement","HTMLTableColElement","HTMLTableElement","HTMLTableRowElement","HTMLTableSectionElement","HTMLTextAreaElement","HTMLTitleElement","HTMLTrackElement","HTMLUListElement","HTMLUnknownElement","HTMLVideoElement","HashChangeEvent","IceCandidate","Image","ImageData","Int16Array","Int32Array","Int8Array","KeyboardEvent","Markdown","MediaController","MediaError","MediaList","MediaStreamEvent","MessageChannel","MessageEvent","MessagePort","MimeType","MimeTypeArray","MouseEvent","MutationEvent","NamedNodeMap","Node","NodeFilter","NodeList","Notation","Notification","OfflineAudioCompletionEvent","Option","OverflowEvent","PERSISTENT","PR","PR_SHOULD_USE_CONTINUATION","PageTransitionEvent","Plugin","PluginArray","PopStateEvent","ProcessingInstruction","ProgressEvent","RGBColor","RTCIceCandidate","RTCSessionDescription","Range","RangeException","Rect","SQLException","SVGAElement","SVGAltGlyphDefElement","SVGAltGlyphElement","SVGAltGlyphItemElement","SVGAngle","SVGAnimateColorElement","SVGAnimateElement","SVGAnimateMotionElement","SVGAnimateTransformElement","SVGAnimatedAngle","SVGAnimatedBoolean","SVGAnimatedEnumeration","SVGAnimatedInteger","SVGAnimatedLength","SVGAnimatedLengthList","SVGAnimatedNumber","SVGAnimatedNumberList","SVGAnimatedPreserveAspectRatio","SVGAnimatedRect","SVGAnimatedString","SVGAnimatedTransformList","SVGCircleElement","SVGClipPathElement","SVGColor","SVGComponentTransferFunctionElement","SVGCursorElement","SVGDefsElement","SVGDescElement","SVGDocument","SVGElement","SVGElementInstance","SVGElementInstanceList","SVGEllipseElement","SVGException","SVGFEBlendElement","SVGFEColorMatrixElement","SVGFEComponentTransferElement","SVGFECompositeElement","SVGFEConvolveMatrixElement","SVGFEDiffuseLightingElement","SVGFEDisplacementMapElement","SVGFEDistantLightElement","SVGFEDropShadowElement","SVGFEFloodElement","SVGFEFuncAElement","SVGFEFuncBElement","SVGFEFuncGElement","SVGFEFuncRElement","SVGFEGaussianBlurElement","SVGFEImageElement","SVGFEMergeElement","SVGFEMergeNodeElement","SVGFEMorphologyElement","SVGFEOffsetElement","SVGFEPointLightElement","SVGFESpecularLightingElement","SVGFESpotLightElement","SVGFETileElement","SVGFETurbulenceElement","SVGFilterElement","SVGFontElement","SVGFontFaceElement","SVGFontFaceFormatElement","SVGFontFaceNameElement","SVGFontFaceSrcElement","SVGFontFaceUriElement","SVGForeignObjectElement","SVGGElement","SVGGlyphElement","SVGGlyphRefElement","SVGGradientElement","SVGHKernElement","SVGImageElement","SVGLength","SVGLengthList","SVGLineElement","SVGLinearGradientElement","SVGMPathElement","SVGMarkerElement","SVGMaskElement","SVGMatrix","SVGMetadataElement","SVGMissingGlyphElement","SVGNumber","SVGNumberList","SVGPaint","SVGPathElement","SVGPathSeg","SVGPathSegArcAbs","SVGPathSegArcRel","SVGPathSegClosePath","SVGPathSegCurvetoCubicAbs","SVGPathSegCurvetoCubicRel","SVGPathSegCurvetoCubicSmoothAbs","SVGPathSegCurvetoCubicSmoothRel","SVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticAbs","SVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticRel","SVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticSmoothAbs","SVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticSmoothRel","SVGPathSegLinetoAbs","SVGPathSegLinetoHorizontalAbs","SVGPathSegLinetoHorizontalRel","SVGPathSegLinetoRel","SVGPathSegLinetoVerticalAbs","SVGPathSegLinetoVerticalRel","SVGPathSegList","SVGPathSegMovetoAbs","SVGPathSegMovetoRel","SVGPatternElement","SVGPoint","SVGPointList","SVGPolygonElement","SVGPolylineElement","SVGPreserveAspectRatio","SVGRadialGradientElement","SVGRect","SVGRectElement","SVGRenderingIntent","SVGSVGElement","SVGScriptElement","SVGSetElement","SVGStopElement","SVGStringList","SVGStyleElement","SVGSwitchElement","SVGSymbolElement","SVGTRefElement","SVGTSpanElement","SVGTextContentElement","SVGTextElement","SVGTextPathElement","SVGTextPositioningElement","SVGTitleElement","SVGTransform","SVGTransformList","SVGUnitTypes","SVGUseElement","SVGVKernElement","SVGViewElement","SVGViewSpec","SVGZoomAndPan","SVGZoomEvent","Selection","SessionDescription","SharedWorker","SpeechInputEvent","StackExchange","Storage","StorageEvent","StyleSheet","StyleSheetList","TEMPORARY","Text","TextEvent","TextMetrics","TextTrack","TextTrackCue","TextTrackCueList","TextTrackList","TimeRanges","TouchEvent","TrackEvent","UIEvent","URL","Uint16Array","Uint32Array","Uint8Array","Uint8ClampedArray","WebGLActiveInfo","WebGLBuffer","WebGLContextEvent","WebGLFramebuffer","WebGLProgram","WebGLRenderbuffer","WebGLRenderingContext","WebGLShader","WebGLShaderPrecisionFormat","WebGLTexture","WebGLUniformLocation","WebKitAnimationEvent","WebKitBlobBuilder","WebKitCSSFilterValue","WebKitCSSKeyframeRule","WebKitCSSKeyframesRule","WebKitCSSMatrix","WebKitCSSRegionRule","WebKitCSSTransformValue","WebKitIntent","WebKitMediaSource","WebKitMutationObserver","WebKitPoint","WebKitSourceBuffer","WebKitSourceBufferList","WebKitTransitionEvent","WebSocket","WheelEvent","Window","WinterBash","Worker","XMLDocument","XMLHttpRequest","XMLHttpRequestException","XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent","XMLHttpRequestUpload","XMLSerializer","XPathEvaluator","XPathException","XPathResult","XSLTProcessor","__qc","_gaq","_gat","_qevents","addEventListener","alert","apiCallbacks","applicationCache","atob","blur","btoa","captureEvents","careers_adselector","careers_adurl","careers_companycssurl","careers_cssurl","careers_leaderboardcssurl","chrome","clearInterval","clearTimeout","clientInformation","close","closed","confirm","console","crypto","defaultStatus","defaultstatus","devicePixelRatio","dispatchEvent","document","event","external","find","focus","frameElement","frames","gaGlobal","gauth","genuwine","getComputedStyle","getMatchedCSSRules","getSelection","history","i","initFadingHelpText","initTagRenderer","innerHeight","innerWidth","jQuery","jQuery171005593172716908157_1357215797040","jQuery171005593172716908157_1357215797041","length","localStorage","location","locationbar","matchMedia","menubar","moveBy","moveScroller","moveTo","name","navigator","offscreenBuffering","onabort","onbeforeunload","onblur","oncanplay","oncanplaythrough","onchange","onclick","oncontextmenu","ondblclick","ondeviceorientation","ondrag","ondragend","ondragenter","ondragleave","ondragover","ondragstart","ondrop","ondurationchange","onemptied","onended","onerror","onfocus","onhashchange","oninput","oninvalid","onkeydown","onkeypress","onkeyup","onload","onloadeddata","onloadedmetadata","onloadstart","onmessage","onmousedown","onmousemove","onmouseout","onmouseover","onmouseup","onmousewheel","onoffline","ononline","onpagehide","onpageshow","onpause","onplay","onplaying","onpopstate","onprogress","onratechange","onreset","onresize","onscroll","onsearch","onseeked","onseeking","onselect","onstalled","onstorage","onsubmit","onsuspend","ontimeupdate","onunload","onvolumechange","onwaiting","onwebkitanimationend","onwebkitanimationiteration","onwebkitanimationstart","onwebkittransitionend","open","openDatabase","opener","outerHeight","outerWidth","pageXOffset","pageYOffset","parent","performance","personalbar","postMessage","prepareEditor","prettyPrint","prettyPrintOne","print","profileLink","prompt","quantserve","releaseEvents","removeEventListener","resizeBy","resizeTo","sanitizeAndSplitTags","screen","screenLeft","screenTop","screenX","screenY","scriptSrc","scroll","scrollBy","scrollTo","scrollX","scrollY","scrollbars","self","sessionStorage","setInterval","setTimeout","showFadingHelpText","showModalDialog","status","statusbar","stop","styleCode","styleMedia","t","tagRenderer","tagRendererRaw","toolbar","top","uh","v","v8Intl","votesCast","webkitAudioContext","webkitAudioPannerNode","webkitCancelAnimationFrame","webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame","webkitConvertPointFromNodeToPage","webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode","webkitIDBCursor","webkitIDBDatabase","webkitIDBDatabaseException","webkitIDBFactory","webkitIDBIndex","webkitIDBKeyRange","webkitIDBObjectStore","webkitIDBRequest","webkitIDBTransaction","webkitIndexedDB","webkitIntent","webkitMediaStream","webkitNotifications","webkitPostMessage","webkitRTCPeerConnection","webkitRequestAnimationFrame","webkitRequestFileSystem","webkitResolveLocalFileSystemURL","webkitStorageInfo","webkitURL","window"];
```

So, these can't / shouldn't be used (at least in Google Chrome), in the global scope. If you declare them as variables in a local scope, you're fine.
This won't contain *all* names used, however, since `arguments` is only available in the function scope, for example.

<sub>Note: this function does return all global variables from your libraries, also</sub>

Comment: `arguments` is not a global variable. It is defined per function as if it were an extra function parameter...

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz: Look at the last line of my answer. I already said that. I'd appreciate it if you'd remove your downvote.

Comment: The problem is that I really don't see what global variables have to do with the question that was asked.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz: The global vars my function returns are most likely used somewhere, but are easily overwritten, possibly breaking your code / page / libraries. As such, I think they definitely _"are not true reserved words, but will cause still problems"_
Meaning this is a perfectly fine answer to the question, which you downvoted. If you don't see how a answer answers a question, __Ask for clarification__. Don't blindly downvote it.

Comment: Ok, I will stay out of a lengthy dispute here but you *can* definitely define a local variable with the name `document` without breaking anything anywhere else in the code.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't. But I'll clarify that this only applies to the global scope.